# Dual monitor on desktop PC - what is required?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I am looking for hardware components to build a new desktop PC and I was wondering what is required in order to have dual monitors. Just a special graphics card with two outputs?

If so could you recommend me one or two graphics cards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the OS (Windows or MAC), interface (PCI-Express, AGP or PCI) or budget it will be difficult, if not impossible, to make a recommendation.

Look for dual output cards - they usually come with either two DVI or one VGA and one DVI output.

You can also get cards with one output that can be split between multiple monitors too.

Comment: How can you use a split?

Comment: The card will come with a splitter cable as it's output is neither DVI or VGA. It's difficult to explain without images though.

Comment: I understand. However it must be designed to be able to split from the factory, right?

Answer (score 3):

Any current video card with two outputs will do, at least in Windows.

You can also add an additional video card if you have one already.

What type of interface PCI-E, AGP, PCI

Do you have on-board video, or do you already have a video card?

What OS?

Comment: it will be PCI-EXpress on Windows 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In our company we put up to 4, 6 or even 10 monitors to a single computer.

The actual solution is to go for Matrox DualHead, nVidia MuliView or other graphics cards with same specs.

Each card gives you room up to two screens which you can use simultaniously.

These cards also allow you to spread your taskbar across all the connected screens. (Which actually converts all connected screens to one single screen. -> resolution would be like "3096x1024" or even more.

Solution for your setup would be to buy one of these DualScreen cards and use the built in card for the third screen.

These cards don't cost that much nowadays and PNY / Matrox build these.

(My answer from [Three monitors setup on machine with integrated graphic card](https://superuser.com/questions/24376/three-monitors-setup-on-machine-with-integrated-graphic-card/24569#24569))

---

Though, I have tried a Matrox Graphics Card on a Windows 7 Machine and the driver support is pretty poor at the moment.

I would consider trying out a nVidia Quadro or a PNY - Yet I didn't have the opportunity to try these out on my Windows 7 Machine..