# Using both integrated graphic card and a PCIe GPU

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, integrated-graphics

**How do I know whether it's possible to use both integrated graphic card and a PCIe one on a Gigabyte G33-DS3R motherboard?**

I saw some [other question](https://superuser.com/questions/24376/three-monitors-setup-on-machine-with-integrated-graphic-card) whose some answers tends to suggest it's not always the case that you both the integrated and PCIe graphics at the same time.

How I can make sure before buying a graphic card?

Comment: Check with the motherboard manufacturer?

Comment: Gigabyte product page: http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2535#ov doesn't seem to touch upon this topic.